# how to specify a custom HTTP method in TIdHTTP?

Tags: delphi, postman, idhttp

I need to do a call with TIDHTTP by specifying a custom HTTP method.

In postman I achieve this by typing the method name in the dropdown where I can choose between GET/POST/PUT/...:

[image: custom method in postman]

how to achieve this in TIdHttp? In this example the HTTP method is not GET but GO (GO of course is custom and not standard).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`TIdHTTP` has a public `Request.Method` property, which you might be tempted to use, however that won't work, because the `TIdCustomHTTP.DoRequest()` method (which does all of the actual work) overwrites that property with its own `AMethod` parameter.  So, you will have to call `DoRequest()` directly instead:

```pascal
procedure DoRequest(const AMethod: TIdHTTPMethod; AURL: string;
  ASource, AResponseContent: TStream; AIgnoreReplies: array of Int16); virtual;
```

`TIdHTTPMethod` is just a `string`, so you can pass in any method name you want.

However, `DoRequest()` is declared as `protected` in `TIdCustomHTTP` <sup>1</sup>, so you will have to use a descendant/accessor class to reach it, eg:

```pascal
type
  TIdHTTPAccess = class(TIdHTTP)
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TIdHTTPAccess(IdHTTP1).DoRequest('GO', 'http://127.0.0.1:1308/...', ParamsAsNeeded...);
end;
```

Or, you can use a `class helper` instead (Delphi 2006+ only), eg:

```pascal
type
  TIdHTTPHelper = class helper for TIdHTTP
    procedure Go(AURL: String; ParamsAsNeeded...);
  end;

procedure TIdHTTPHelper.Go(AURL: String; ParamsAsNeeded...);
begin
  DoRequest('GO', AURL, ParamsAsNeeded...);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdHTTP1.Go('http://127.0.0.1:1308/...', ParamsAsNeeded...);
end;
```

<sup>1: There is an open ticket in Indy's issue tracker about this: [#254 Make TIdHTTP.DoRequest() public](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/254).</sup>